# Upload data folder file to spiff of esp8266

Tags: arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi, esptool, arduino-cli

I'm trying to upload an Arduino file and its associated data folder to an esp8266 using Arduino-cli, but I'm having trouble uploading the contents of the data folder to the esp8266   SPIFF memory.

I am not able to find a way to solve this problem.
Can anyone suggest a way to solve this problem?

I am able to upload Arduino file and data folder to spiff using Arduino IDE. But using CLI i am not able to find way how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a /data folder.
- ESP-01 FS: 64k.
- Replace COM10.

```
mkspiffs.exe -c data/ -p 256 -b 4096 -s 65536 out.spiffs
esptool.exe -cd nodemcu -cb 115200 -cp COM10 -ca 0xeb000 -cf out.spiffs
```

Comment: It helps a lot , thank you the  replay @Tyler2P